# Filtering a collection deep in an object graph

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, asp.net-web-api

Here is what I am trying to do:
My ASP.NET Web API accepts a chart "id", a "startTimestamp", and an "endTimestamp" from the client. I need the Web API to select only the "MeasureData" (see the attached EF5 conceptual model diagram) that is inside of the timestamp range defined by startTimestamp and endTimestamp. My Web API returns a JSON AmSerialChart object graph to the client. I then parse the JSON object graph and build a chart using the amCharts Javascript API. The chart only shows data between the startTimestamp and endTimestamp.

I can't figure out how to write a LINQ expression in my controller that will filter the MeasureData and return an AmSerialChart object with filtered MeasureData.

Here is one failed attempt:

```
AmSerialChart amserialchart =
(AmSerialChart)db.AmSerialCharts
.Find(id)
.Graphs
.Select(g => g.Measure)
.SelectMany(m => m.MeasureData)
.Where(md => md.Timestamp >= startDate && md.Timestamp <= endDate);
```

"db.AmSerialCharts.Find(id)" finds the appropriate chart entity, but I'm not sure how to navigate through the rest of the object graph to get to the MeasureData filter.

Comment: What is the point of the Graph table?

Comment: @Justin - A Graph is a chart object. Each AmSerialChart can have one of more graphs. Eventually, I will add properties to the Graph objects, such as line color, line thickness, etc. Each Graph is associated with exactly one Measure. However, a Measure can be graphed by more than one Graph.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a single-line LINQ is not the best solution for a problem.  Even if it's possible, readability will often go out the window.  Sometimes it's just best to manually do the work.

The problem with your request is that you want an `AmSerialChart` object with a full object hierarchy pruned to match your timeframe.  The issue is that a basic `Select` won't do that. It will want to generate a new list or new objects.

I think your best solution is to "copy" your object hierarchy rather than trying to LINQ it:

```
var fullChart = charts.Where(c => c.Id == id).Single();
var result = new AmSerialChart()
{
  Id = fullChart.Id,
  Name = fullChart.Name,
  Description = fullChart.Description,
  FirstTimestamp = fullChart.FirstTimestamp,
  LastTimestamp = fullChart.LastTimestamp,
  Graphs = new List<Graph>()
};

foreach (var graph in fullChart.Graphs)
{
  var measure = graph.Measure;

  var newMeasure = new Measure()
  {
    Id = measure.Id,
    // Copy the rest of data

    MeasureData = new List<MeasureData>()
  };

  foreach (var measureData in measure.MeasureData)
  {
    if (measureData.Timestamp >= startDate && measureData.Timestamp <= endDate)
    {
      var newMeasureData = new MeasureData()
      {
        Id = measureData.Id,
        // Copy the rest of data
      };
      newMeasure.MeasureData.Add(newMeasureData);
    }
  }

  if (newMeasure.MeasureData.Count() > 0)
  {
    var newGraph = new Graph()
    {
      Id = graph.Id,
      // Copy the rest of data

      Measure = newMeasure
    };
    result.Graphs.Add(newGraph);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip about skipping right down through the Measure object. However, your answer returns an IEnumerable of MeasureData instead of a AmSerialChart. Testing out your answer also made me realize that I don't think I want a SelectMany operator because it is flattening all the MeasureDatas across all Measures.

Comment: Do you want an `AmSerialChart` object with it's `Graph` objects and `MeasureData` pruned to only include that data that's within the bounds of your timeframe?  If `AmSerialChart` identified by `id` has no such measure data, do you still want the `AmSerialChart`?

Comment: It may be difficult to give you an object filtered to your requested data.  The reason being that your source object is a "complete" object with the full data and you'll have to copy all objects down your hierarchy so that you're not modifying your original "full data" versions.  You won't just be able to "select" a pruned version without possible negative repercussions.

Comment: I understand your approach (I was actually headed down the same path myself), but it seems like copying the object hierarchy duplicates a ton of code.

Answer (score 1):

> filter the MeasureData and return an AmSerialChart object

You better use `Any()`:

```
var measureData = charts.Where(c => c.Id == id
     && c.Graphs.Any(g => g.Measure.MeasureData
    .Any(md => md.Timestamp >= startDate && md.Timestamp <= endDate)))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

or `SingleOrDefault()` if not more than 1 match is expected.

Comment: Although this answer is returning a AmSerialChart object (+1), it isn't filtering out the MeasureData entities that fall outside of the startDate-endDate range.

Comment: If you use `All()` in stead of `Any()` (twice) you will select an `AmSerialChart` of which _all_ Graphs _only_ have MeasureData in the specified interval. Usually this is e very (too) strict condition, but it may be correct with your data.

Comment: When I use `Any()` (twice), all the MeasureData are returned as long as at least one of their timestamps is within the range. When I use `All()` (twice), none of the MeasureData are returned if at least one of their timestamps is outside of the range. This makes sense, but what I'm trying to do is return the MeasureData whose timestamps are within the range and exclude the MeasureData whose timestamps are outside of the range. It seems to me that I should be applying the `Where()` operator against the MeasureData collection, but I'm not sure how to do that in within your LINQ statement.

Comment: You could start the query with the `MeasureData` in the range and select `Measure` > `Graph` > `AmSerialChart`, but I think that would give the same result as `All`.